# Can you create a search bar in a Quarto HTML document like you can for a website?

Tags: html, r, quarto

I am trying to make a searchable HTML document in Quarto using R, like you would set search: true in the yaml of a Quarto Website. I cannot create a website at work so that is not an option. Is there a work around to add a search bar to an html document?

Comment: if you open the html document in your browser and press `ctrl-f` what happens?

Comment: yes that works, but that is not what I want. If there is a way to create an actual search bar like you can in a pkgdown site or quarto website, that is what I am after

Comment: As far as I know, the search bar isn't functional when you output .html from a Quarto website, it needs to be a live website. You could `quarto preview` and view the website on localhost - is that an option?

Comment: it is not, I decided to use the DT package in certain spots to get around the serach, not ideal but it works